# Custom layout/group switching keys in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard-layout

I'm using Ubuntu (Karmic) and 2 keyboard layouts.
Using the gnome settings, I managed to set it to switch with Alt+Shift (windows style), but I really want to limit it to Right Alt + Right Shift, but that option isn't available in the gnome wizard.
I've opened gconf-editor and found the `kbd` configuration, but trying to add 'r' or 'right_' prefixes to the keys didn't help.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you could make a global shortcut assigned to Right Alt + Right Shift that calls a script that switches between the two. Keep in Mind Right Alt may actually be AltGr.

My Personal favorite is setting Scroll Lock LED to be a layout indicator and Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Scroll Lock swaps between layouts.